# Different languages/keyboard layouts for different users - Debian

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am running Debian 8 Jessie. Would it be possible to set user-specific languages and keyboard layouts for users in Debian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You need to edit the `~/.bashrc` file.

As an example, consider an English system (`en_US.UTF-8` locale/language and `us`) keyboard. To give a specific user an italian environment, you need to edit its `~/.bashrc` file adding the following rows:

```
export LC_ALL=it_IT.UTF-8
export LANG=it_IT.UTF-8
loadkeys it
```

Comment: Is there some place where I can find a list of all keyboard layouts and languages?